# Constant Gauss curvature $K$ surface cannot contain a plane triangle

Tags: differential-geometry

How to approach a proof towards a conclusion that constant Gauss curvature $K$ surface ( in $\mathbb R^3) $ cannot contain an equilateral (planar) triangle on it.

Please indicate only the approach, not its proof.

Comment: Well, one would start with a definition of a planar triangle, I think. With one definition, the claim will be immediate. With another, it would use Gauss-Bonnet formula. With the third definition, it would require more work, such as a reading comparison theorem.

Comment: To clarify: You're assuming that the *edges* of the triangle, but not its face, are contained in the surface? Even so, as @MoisheKohan has suggested, the result follows immediately from Gauss-Bonnet.

Comment: And you should also assume $K\ne 0$. :) And there is no need for constant curvature, only $K<0$ or $K>0$.

Comment: Constant $K$ for a triangle area/patch and varying $K$ for a differential surface area element.. right?

Comment: @Narasimham: I could not parse your sentence in the comment but, as I suggested above, you should edit your question to make it precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every plane triangle has Gaussian curvature 0. As I bet you already know, Gauss curvature $K$ is the product of the two [principal curvatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_curvature).

Thus, since you have said in the post that you only want the approach, not the proof, I shall refrain myself from concluding. However, I will say that you are asking for a region with $k_1=k_2=0$, and your surface has $K = k_1\cdot k_2$. If $K\neq 0$...

Comment: A surface of $K=0$ can belong also to any cylinder, any cone or any developable helicoid and not necessarily only to the plane. I.e., both principal curvatures need not vanish.

Comment: @Narasimham I intended to say that if you have a plane triangle, then both principal curvatures need to vanish, not the other way around.